# counting number of lines in a text/csv file using OSB

Tags: csv, flat-file, osb

I have a CSV file, I need to count the total number of lines in that file. This I have to use in OSB. My requirement is I have to count total no of lines in the $body file (CSV/flat file) and subtract header and footer lines from it, using either XSLT/Xquery.

EX:

```
header,1, @total_no_of_detal@
detail,1
detail,2
detail,3
"
"
detail,n

footer, 1
```

If suppose i have 10 detail lines, and I am getting body of the file as shown above,

then in the final file, I have to change the body of the file as:

```
header,1, 10
detail,1
detail,2
detail,3
"
"
detail,n

footer, 1
```

Please advice how to do this in OSB.

Comment: Have removed the references to XSLT: As the source is not XML I don't see the relevance.

Comment: Hi Jon,   Yes my output file is not XML, it is a CSV file, I want to know how I can count the no of lines in this CSV file using XSLT/Xquery.

Comment: XSLT is an XML parser. If you've not got XML, you either need to make XML, or to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the flat file is just red into the `$body` variable, here is how you can count the lines:

```
fn:count(fn:tokenize($body/text(), '(\r\n?|\n\r?)'))
```